# Callback in Bender's decomposition

Tags: callback, cplex, decomposition

I am learning Bender's decomposition method and I want to use that in a small instance. I started from "bendersatsp.py" example in CPLEX. When I run this example with my problem, I got the following error. Could you please let me know what the problem is and how I can fix it? In the following you can see the modifications in lazy constraints function. I have two decision variables in master problem "z_{ik}" and "u_{k}" that would incorporate as constant in the workerLp.

```
class BendersLazyConsCallback(LazyConstraintCallback):       


def __call__(self): 
    print("shoma")    
    v       = self.v
    u       = self.u
    z       = self.z
    print ("u:", u)
    print ("z:", z)
    workerLP = self.workerLP
    boxty = len(u)

    #scenarios=self.scenarios2
    ite=len(z)
    print ("ite:", ite)
    print ("boxty:", boxty)

    # Get the current x solution
    sol1 = []
    sol2 = []
    sol3 = []

    print("okkkk")


    for k in range(1, boxty+1): 
        sol1.append([]) 
        sol1[k-1]= [self.get_values(u[k-1])]; 
        print ("sol1:", sol1[k-1])


    for i in range(1, ite+1): 
        sol2.append([])
        sol2[i-1]= self.get_values(z[i-1]);
        print ("sol2:", sol2[i-1])


    for i in range(1, ite+1):
        sol3.append([])
        sol3[i-1]= self.get_values(v[i-1]);
        #print ("sol3:", sol3[i-1])


    # Benders' cut separation
    if workerLP.separate(sol3,sol1,sol2,v,u,z):
        self.add(cut = workerLP.cutLhs, sense = "G", rhs = workerLP.cutRhs)
```

CPLEX Error 1006: Error during callback.

benders(sys.argv[1][0], datafile)

cpx.solve()

_proc.mipopt(self._env._e, self._lp)

check_status(env, status)

raise callback_exception

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: Can you show the actual traceback (i.e., edit your question)? What is in datafile? Did you make any other modifications to the example?

Comment: $rkersh, I updated my question and error.

Comment: Aren't you trying to index an empty list with the following statement: `sol2[i-1][k-1]= self.get_values(z[i-1][k-1]);`? In the previous statement you append an empty list, and then you try to access element `k-1` with `sol2[i-1][k-1]`.

Comment: @rkersh, thank you! the problem is exactly the empty list so I updated the function in the question. Master problem solution in the first iteration is zero so when ite: 7 and boxty: 2     `u: [14, 15]
z: [[16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21], [22, 23], [24, 25], [26, 27], [28, 29]]
sol1: [0.0]
sol1: [0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]
sol2: [0.0, 0.0]`

Comment: it seems ok to me and I could not find the problem. Do you have any idea?